# What is best practices by config graylog rotation/retantion indexes?

Tags: database-indexes, graylog

What is best practices by config graylog rotation/retantion indexes?

Comment: Take a look at my answer on serverfault for a similar question: https://serverfault.com/a/1063895/318166

Answer (score 0):

If using open source, set retention to delete after reaching the set number of indices.

If using enterprise, set it to archive, then delete.